# Is a MySql connection with Broken Pipe or EOFException = null?

Tags: java, mysql

Just curious, does a MySql connection with Broken Pipe or EOFException = null?

I'm asking cause it might be causing a logic error in my code. Or is there a way to simulate the broken pipe or eof faster? Currently I'm doing database pooling and I do a check where is the conn !=null, counter++ to keep track of the number of connections in use, but if the above is true, I will do a counter++ when the connection is not valid because it does not actually return a null but an object that is not valid. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether the connection is still valid or not, the no reference to the connection instance will be == to null, unless it is actually null. This is entirely unrelated to whether the connection instance is in a usable state.

A common method to determine the latter is to send a simple query through the connection, after it has been dormant for a while. Depending on your database, it could be as simple as „SELECT 1“

Comment: Yes that was the work around I did and just used 2 checks instead. If the connection if valid and not null.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really enough context to answer your question.  (Hint: post the actual code!!)

However, in general an unexpected `null` will result in a `NullPointerException`, and not some subclass of `IOException`.